# IE10 crash on a tab when use caps lock on a password field

Tags: bsod, internet-explorer-10, capslock

I have a weird issue with an HP ProBook 4530s laptop on W7. When using IE10 and trying to enter a password (on all websites : gmail, yahoo, etc.) a tooltip informs me when I use CAPS LOCK. Problem is that when this tooltip appear, I can't write anymore in any field of the page ! Seems that the focus on fields is definitely lost.

I tried with an USB keyboard, same. No problem with Chrome, but I can't change user habits.
I see that in IE10 there is a JS property called "msCapsLockWarningOff" but I don't know how to change this JS option for all browser, don't know if it's even possible.

Last point, computer user said to me that sometimes when she have this issue a BSOD appears. I haven't be able to reproduce it.
All updates have been done.

Does someone has already encountered this problem?

Thanks

Comment: This happens on every single website?  if it doesn't I would rephrase that statement.

Comment: Yes it happens on every single website. No exception.